# Subdomain not working any more

Tags: apache2

I already had a subdomain working for a long time, but now, from one moment to another, it's not working any more. Does anybody have an idea why? I recently installed ownCloud on the server, maybe this somehow could be the reason?

FYI: I'm getting a 301, like the subdomain never existed... I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and apache2....